# NATS persistent message Java Client

Tags: java, message-queue, nats-streaming-server

Does anyone have experience using the NATS Streaming Server combined with a Java client? Specifically I can't figure out how to retrieve messages using the Java Client that are sent when a subscriber is offline.

I can see using the [Go client](https://github.com/nats-io/go-nats-streaming) that I can publish a message and later add a subscription to retrieve all published messages. This is in the NATS Streaming [Getting Started](http://nats.io/documentation/streaming/nats-streaming-quickstart/) documentation and it works as advertised.

> Publish several messages. For each publication you should get a
>   result.

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/nats-io/go-nats-streaming/examples
go run stan-pub.go foo "msg one"
Published [foo] : 'msg one'
$ go run stan-pub.go foo "msg two"
Published [foo] : 'msg two'
$ go run stan-pub.go foo "msg three"
Published [foo] : 'msg three'
```

> Run the subscriber client.
>   Use the --all flag to receive all published messages.

```
$ go run stan-sub.go --all -c test-cluster -id myID foo
Connected to nats://localhost:4222 clusterID: [test-cluster] clientID: [myID]
subscribing with DeliverAllAvailable
Listening on [foo], clientID=[myID], qgroup=[] durable=[]
[#1] Received on [foo]: 'sequence:1 subject:"foo" data:"msg one" timestamp:1465962202884478817 '
[#2] Received on [foo]: 'sequence:2 subject:"foo" data:"msg two" timestamp:1465962208545003897 '
[#3] Received on [foo]: 'sequence:3 subject:"foo" data:"msg three" timestamp:1465962215567601196
```

I'm trying to do this using the [NATS Java client](https://github.com/nats-io/jnats). I can't figure out if it's just that I'm not finding the analogous method calls or if the feature doesn't exist in the Java client.

Here's what I've tried

```
    import io.nats.client.Connection;
import io.nats.client.ConnectionFactory;
import io.nats.client.Constants;
import io.nats.client.Message;
import io.nats.client.SyncSubscription;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

public class NatsTest2 {

  private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    final ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(Constants.DEFAULT_URL);
    try (final Connection conn = factory.createConnection()) {
      // Simple Async Subscriber
      final String expectMessage = "Yum, cookies " + System.currentTimeMillis();
      works(conn, expectMessage);
      broken(conn, expectMessage);
    }
  }

  private static void works(Connection conn, String expectMessage) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    final String queue = Long.toString(random.nextLong());
    System.out.print(queue + "=>");
    try (final SyncSubscription subscription = conn.subscribeSync(queue)) {
      conn.publish(queue, expectMessage.getBytes());
      subscribe(subscription);
    }
  }

  private static void broken(Connection conn, String expectMessage) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    final String queue = Long.toString(random.nextLong());
    System.out.print(queue + "=>");
    conn.publish(queue, expectMessage.getBytes());
    try (final SyncSubscription subscription = conn.subscribeSync(queue)) {
      subscribe(subscription);
    }
  }

  private static void subscribe(SyncSubscription subscription) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    final Message message = subscription.nextMessage(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(new String(message.getData()));
  }
}
```

This gives output

```
-8522002637987832314=>Yum, cookies 1473462495040
-3024385525006291780=>Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Channel timed out waiting for items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `nats-streaming-server`, you need to use the [java-nats-streaming](https://github.com/nats-io/java-nats-streaming) client. The feature you're looking for (subscription to historical messages) only exists in that client.

Regardless, here's why you saw what you did with the `jnats` client:

`nats-streaming-server` currently embeds a NATS server (`gnatsd`), and therefore allows standard NATS functionality for regular NATS clients, which is what you're seeing.

In your example code, `works()` happens to work because your subscription is already created before you publish your message (in other words, your `try-with-resources` block guarantees the subscription is already active before anything else happens). Therefore you're not really receiving a message that was published in the past; you're receiving a message that was published after the subscription started.

The `broken()` example *doesn't* work because it actually *is* publishing the message before the subscription is created, and the message is discarded by the server because there is no interest (yet).